# React: Limit action to a single component

Tags: reactjs

This is a container:

```
render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ul className="list-group" id="contact-list">
          {this.returnContactList().map(
            (contact) =>
              <li key={contact.date.N} className="list-group-item">
                <ContactCard contact={contact} onFormSubmit={this.handleSubmit} summaryHidden={this.state.summaryHidden} />
              </li>
          )}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

This is what I have as a component:

```
import React from 'react';
import '../Contacts.css';
const ContactCard = ({ contact, onFormSubmit, summaryHidden }) => {

    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={onFormSubmit}>submit</button>
            <div style={{ display: summaryHidden ? 'block' : 'none' }}>
                Summary
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default ContactCard;
```

This renders list of contacts. But when I click button, the text `Summary` gets applied to all components. I want to limit it to a single component only. How to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only have one "summaryHidden" variable in your container. You need a separate one for each component (maybe store them on the contact objects in the map) if you want the summaries to be hidden in some components and not others.